# Creating index name from field value in filebeat configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat

This is my filebeat.yml file:

```
filebeat.config:
    modules:
        path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
        reload.enabled: false

processors:
    - add_cloud_metadata: ~
    - add_docker_metadata: ~
    - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~

output.elasticsearch:
    hosts: '${ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS:elasticsearch:9200}'
    username: '${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME:}'
    password: '${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD:}'

setup.kibana:
    host: '${KIBANA_HOST}'
    ssl.enabled: false

filebeat.modules:
    - module: kibana
    - module: elasticsearch

fields_under_root: true
json.keys_under_root: true

filebeat.inputs:
    - type: log
      enabled: true
      fields:
          my_type: 'inventory'
      index: 'test-%{[fields.my_type]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}'
      paths:
          - /var/log/kibana/kibana.log

setup.ilm.overwrite: true
setup.ilm.enabled: false
setup.template.name: 'test-%{[fields.my_type]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}'
setup.template.pattern: 'test-%{[fields.my_type]}-*'
```

I want create index name from my field value ( specifically log file name )
It works when I try to do it with agent fields like

```
%{[agent.version]}
```

but got error when I am trying to make name from my custom field or other ones available

```
%{[file.name]} or %{[fields.my_type]}
```

This is the error from filebeat log:

```
ERROR [publisher] pipeline/client.go:106 Failed to publish event: key not found
```

Thanks for any hints

Comment: Did you try just `%{[my_type]}`?

Comment: @Filip Yes I did.

Comment: The way I got it worked is by not using any fields in the template name and pattern but only in the output index configuration.

Answer (score 0):

based on what you have posted, it looks like your `index` declaration is in the wrong place, as it's in the input not the output

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/elasticsearch-output.html#index-option-es describes what you want to do, but try this;

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["http://eshost:9200"]
  index: "%{[fields.my_type]}-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
```

and remove it from the inputs

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have also tried it to put into output, but with the same results - error: key not found. For configuration it should not matter where you put it and I want to specifically create index name per input.